# Use metadata in filename when saving harbor input Liquidsoap

Tags: icecast, liquidsoap

So I have an instance of Liquidsoap, which I am using to stream to an Icecast server.

I'd like to record any live broadcasts that take place automatically, which I am now doing and is working well.

What I'd like to do is use the metadata (specifically the songname) of the live show when creating the mp3 archive.

```
                #!/usr/local/bin/liquidsoap

            set("log.file",true)
            set("log.file.path","/var/log/liquidsoap/radiostation.log")
            set("log.stdout",true)
            set("log.level",3)
            #-------------------------------------

            set("harbor.bind_addr","0.0.0.0")

            #-------------------------------------

            backup_playlist = playlist("/home/radio/playlists/playlist.pls",conservative=true,reload_mode="watch")
            output.dummy(fallible=true,backup_playlist)

            #-------------------------------------

            live_dj = input.harbor(id="live",port=9000,password="XXX", "live")

            date = '%m-%d-%Y'
            time = '%H:%M:%S'
            output.file(%mp3, "/var/www/recorded-shows/#{Title} - Recorded On #{date} At #{time}.mp3", live_dj, fallible=true)

            #time_stamp = '%m-%d-%Y, %H:%M:%S'
            #output.file(%mp3, "/var/www/recorded-shows/live_dj_#{time_stamp}.mp3", live_dj, fallible=true)

            #-------------------------------------

            on_fail = single("/home/radio/fallback/Enei -The Moment Feat DRS.mp3")

            #-------------------------------------

            source = fallback(track_sensitive=false,
                              [live_dj, backup_playlist, on_fail])

            # We output the stream to icecast
            output.icecast(%mp3,id="icecast",
                           mount="myradio.mp3",
                           host="localhost", password="XXX",
                           icy_metadata="true",description="cool radio",
                           url="http://myradio.fm",
                           source)
```

I have added #{title} where I would like my song title to appear, sadly though I am unable to get this populate.

My Dj's use BUTT and the show title is connected as part of their connection, so the data should be available pre recording.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is far from being as easy as it seems.

1. The `title` metadata is dynamic, thus not available as a variable on script initialization
2. The filename argument of `output.file` is compiled when the script is initialized

A solution would consist in:

1. Defining a variable reference `title` to populate with live metadata
2. Output to a temporary file
3. Rename the file on close using `on_close` argument with `output.file` (in this case, we can just prepend the title)

This would give the following code (on a Linux box, change `mv` with `ren` on Windows):

```
date = '%m-%d-%Y'
time = '%H:%M:%S'
# Title is a reference
title = ref ""

# Populate with metadata
def get_title(m)
  title := m['title']
end
live_dj = on_metadata(get_title,live_dj)

# Rename file on close
def on_close(filename)
  # Generate new file name
  new_filename = "#{path.dirname(filename)}/#{!title} - #{basename(filename)}"
  # Rename file
  system("mv '#{filename}' '#{new_filename}'")
end

output.file(on_close=on_close, %mp3, "/var/www/recorded-shows/Recorded On #{date} At #{time}.mp3", live_dj, fallible=true)
```

I tested a similar scenario and it works just well. Just beware that this will create a new file every time a DJ disconnects or updates the title. Also keep in mind that time stamps will be resolved by `output.file`.

This is based on the following example from a Liquidsoap dev: https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap/issues/661#issuecomment-439935854)